# key strokes events dont execute in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, key, prism

I'm using WPF MVVM pattern with Prism
im trying to bind keybind to some command

----View---

```
<Canvas Background="Red" Grid.Row="1">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
                    <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding KeyDownCmd}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
                    <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding KeyUpCmd}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>           
        </Canvas>
```

----View Model----

```
       #region Commands
        public DelegateCommand<KeyEventArgs> KeyDownCmd { get; private set; }
        public DelegateCommand<KeyEventArgs> KeyUpCmd { get; private set; }
        
        #endregion

        #region Ctor
        public GameViewModel()
        {
            KeyDownCmd = new DelegateCommand<KeyEventArgs>(KeyDownExecute);
            KeyUpCmd = new DelegateCommand<KeyEventArgs>(KeyUpExecute);            
        } 

        private void KeyUpExecute(KeyEventArgs obj)
        {
           //some code here
        }

        private void KeyDownExecute(KeyEventArgs obj)
        {
             //some code here
        }
```

i also tried to bind to code-behind like this `KeyDown="Canvas_KeyDown"` and nothing

tried to use PreviewKeyDown /PreviewKeyUp and nothing

also tried to bind the key command to the gird above the canvas and to the userControl and nothing

**P.S**
im navigating between pages with viewInjection [as described here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/blob/master/05-ViewInjection/ViewInjection/Views/MainWindow.xaml.cs)

Comment: Have you tried putting the i:Interaction.Triggers stuff on the window instead? I doubt the canvas has a reason to receive key strokes to begin with...

Comment: yes BOTH with events and with code behind

Comment: the active window should always see the previewkeydown event, if you have multiple windows, you'll have to observe the event in all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Canvas` doesn't raise any key stroke events unless it's `Focusable` and focused.

You can make it focusable by setting the property in the XAML but you still have to focus it at some point, for example when it's clicked:

```
private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas canvas = (Canvas)sender;
    Keyboard.Focus(canvas);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Canvas Focusable="True" Background="Red"
        PreviewKeyDown="Canvas_PreviewKeyDown"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    ...
</Canvas>
```

You should probably reconsider your approach and handle the `PreviewKeyDown` of a parent element or a focusable child element of the `Canvas` instead.